# Missing necessary permission - live USB

Tags: usb, permissions, files

The computer froze during updating to Ubuntu version 15.04. After turning it off the system doesnt work anymore. Live USB doesnt recognize the broken installed version of Ubuntu, therefore I dont know hot to repair it. However files are still there, but most of them arent accessible because of the fact that I am user 999 and computer want user 1000 to access given folders.

Please help me get my files back.

Comment: Upgraded from what?

Comment: I was upgrading from Ubuntu 14.04 LTS. The only reason I have decided for it was because I bought a new external monitor (I have a laptop) and there was some glitch that was supposed to be corrected in next version.

Answer (score 0):

There is no official way to upgrade to 15 from 14.04. You would have had to upgrade to 14.10 first. You can try the terminal code below to regain access to files however you may have simply broken/damaged them or the distribution in general.

To change your user id using a live cd.  In a terminal (Ctl Alt T)

```
   find / -uid 999 -exec chown -h 1000 {} +
```

Try running this in root

```
sudo -i
```

Comment: It doesnt work. What I get is maybe 100 "Operation not permited messages." and few "Permission denied ones." I have tried using sudo (tought perhaps it may help) but than nothing happens at all.

Comment: It doesnt work.

Comment: Thank you for trying to help. The solution still doesnt work. It must be simply broken. It is a shame.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for help. Anyway with more luck than reason I have found a solution. Using terminal on live USB I have created new user. This user has number 1000, so it can access files.